Solving a System of Nonlinear PDEs with Finite Element Method (from paper Materialia 1 (2018) 78–88)
I am trying to solve a system of nonlinear PDEs using the finite element method in Mathematica. The system consists of equations for vacancies (V) and self-interstitial atoms (SIAs) and corresponds to the implementation to generate Fig 5 of the paper  Materialia 1 (2018) 78–88. Here are the details of the model:
Model Equations
Vacancies (V)
For vacancies $c_v$, the differential equation is:
$$ \frac{\partial c_v}{\partial t}= \nabla \cdot \left( M \nabla \left( \frac{\delta F}{\delta c_v} \right) \right) - K c_v (c_1 + c_2 + c_3) + P + \xi_v $$
where
$$ \mu = \frac{\delta F}{\delta c_v} = 4 c_v^3 - 6 c_v^2 + 2 c_v - \gamma \nabla^2 c_v $$
and assuming isotropic vacancy diffusivity:
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} M_{v} & 0 \\ 0 & M_{v} \end{pmatrix} $$
Note: $\xi_v$ is the noise term.
Self-Interstitial Atoms (SIAs)
For SIAs $c_i$ ($i=1,2,3$), the differential equation is:
$$ \frac{\partial c_i}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \left( D_i \nabla c_i \right) - K c_i c_v + P_i + \xi_i $$
with diffusivities rotated by 120 degrees with respect to each other:
$$ D_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 10.0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad D_2 = R_{120}^{T} D_1 R_{120}, \quad D_3 = R_{240}^{T} D_1 R_{240} $$
and
$$ P_i = \frac{P}{n} \text{ where } n = 3 $$
and $\xi_i$ is the noise term (Langevin).
Time Discretization
$$ \frac{\partial \text{field}}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\Delta t} \left( \text{field}^{n+1} - \text{field}^{n} \right) $$
My Mathematica Code
Here is the code I have written so far:
<< NDSolve`FEM`
Lx = 100; Ly = 100; nsteps = 100; Δt = 5*10^0;
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Lx, Ly}];

γ = 0.5; K = 0.16; p = 0.016; pv = p; pi = p/3; Mv = 0.3;
noiseAmplitude = 10^(-5); conu0 = 0.0;

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5, 
   "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
mesh["Wireframe"]
n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]];
noise = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
   noiseAmplitude*(RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, n])];
cvf[0][x_, y_] := 0
muf[0][x_, y_] := 0
c1f[0][x_, y_] := 0
c2f[0][x_, y_] := 0
c3f[0][x_, y_] := 0

Plot3D[noise[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh]; (*set up rotations 120 degrees apart*)
angle = Pi/3;
R120 = {{Cos[angle], -Sin[angle]}, {Sin[angle], Cos[angle]}};
R240 = R120 . R120;
D1 = {{10., 0.}, {0., 0.1}};
D2 = Transpose[R120] . (D1 . R120);
D3 = Transpose[R240] . (D1 . R240);

eq = {
   -(cv[x, y] - cvf[i - 1][x, y]) / Δt + 
     Mv Laplacian[mu[x, y], {x, y}] - 
     K cv[x, y] (c1[x, y] + c2[x, y] + c3[x, y]) + pv + 
     noise[x, y] == 
    NeumannValue[0, True],
   (1 - cvf[i - 1][x, y])^2 cv[x, y] + (1 - cv[x, y]) cvf[i - 1][x, y]^2 - 
     mu[x, y] - γ Laplacian[cv[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    NeumannValue[0, True],
   -(c1[x, y] - c1f[i - 1][x, y]) / Δt + 
     Div[D1 . Grad[c1[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
     K c1[x, y] cv[x, y] + pi + noise[x, y] / 3 == 
    NeumannValue[0, True],
   -(c2[x, y] - c2f[i - 1][x, y]) / Δt + 
     Div[D2 . Grad[c2[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
     K c2[x, y] cv[x, y] + pi + noise[x, y] / 3 == 
    NeumannValue[0, True],
   -(c3[x, y] - c3f[i - 1][x, y]) / Δt + 
     Div[D3 . Grad[c3[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
     K c3[x, y] cv[x, y] + pi + noise[x, y] / 3 == 
    NeumannValue[0, True]
   };

Do[{cvf[i], muf[i], c1f[i], c2f[i], c3f[i]} = 
   NDSolveValue[
    eq, {cv, mu, c1, c2, c3}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];, {i, 1, nsteps}]

Errors I am encountering
NDSolveValue::femibcnd: No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for {c1, c2, c3, cv, mu}; the result may not be unique.
DiscretizePDE::femdpop: The FEMLoadElements operator failed.
DiscretizePDE::femdpop: The FEMStiffnessElements operator failed.

Question
How can I correctly implement the boundary conditions of type Neumann and also periodic boundary conditions  and resolve the above errors? Any guidance or suggestions on improving the finite element implementation of this system of nonlinear PDEs in Mathematica would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Where periodic boundary conditions should be implemented?

Values of all fields cv, mu, c1,c2,c3 equal at top/bottom edge y==0/y==L for all x;  and similar for left/right edge x==0/x==L for all y

Function noise is not periodic. How solution could be periodic?

you are right, despite this, I understand that it is still possible to get periodic solution. Model is from paper Materialia 1 (2018) 78–88, see Fig. 5 which shows periodic boundary solution.

Could you give title of this paper or link?

you can find it here https://annas-archive.se/md5/670a290dbb798296a4154215273c16d8

Unfortunately, link is not valid. Could you give title?

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mtla.2018.04.003

Thank you. In the paper they noted that "All calculations are
performed using the Falcon supercomputing system at Idaho National
Laboratory" :)

yes, they used MOOSE FE package. Are you saying this problem cannot be solved with Mathematica?

We can solve but not much. For example, we can solve in one cell, but not 50-100 cells like they did.

Sounds extremely disappointing TBH

Nevertheless, we can see coherent structure even in one cell.

We can solve this system in one cell with periodic boundary conditions. Numerical solution in one cell can be then mapped at large region using TranslationTransform. First, we consider system with two SIAs, we have
<< NDSolve`FEM`
dt = 1./50; nn = 100;
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];

\[Gamma] = 0.5; K0 = 0.16; p = 0.016; pv = p; pi = p/2; Mv = 0.3;
noiseAmplitude = 10^(-5); conu0 = 0.0;

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001];

n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]];
noise = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
   noiseAmplitude*(RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n])];
cvf[0][x_, y_] := 0
muf[0][x_, y_] := 0
c1f[0][x_, y_] := 0
c2f[0][x_, y_] := 0
{mesh["Wireframe"], 
 DensityPlot[noise[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue]} 


(*set up rotations 120 degrees apart*)angle = Pi/3;
R120 = RotationMatrix[2 Pi/3];
R240 = RotationMatrix[4 Pi/3];
D1 = {{10., 0.}, {0., 0.1}}; D2 = {{.1, 0.}, {0., 10}};
(*D2=Transpose[R120].(D1.R120);
D3=Transpose[R240].(D1.R240);*)

eq = {-(cv[x, y] - cvf[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Mv  Laplacian[mu[x, y], {x, y}] - 
     K0  cvf[i - 1][x, y]  (c1[x, y] + c2[x, y]) + pv + noise[x, y] ==
     0, (1 - cvf[i - 1][x, y])^2 cv[x, 
       y] + (1 - cv[x, y]) cvf[i - 1][x, y]^2 - 
     mu[x, y] - \[Gamma]  Laplacian[cv[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    0, -(c1[x, y] - c1f[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Div[D1 . Grad[c1[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
     K0  c1[x, y]  cvf[i - 1][x, y] + pi + noise[x, y]/2 == 
    0, -(c2[x, y] - c2f[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Div[D2 . Grad[c2[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
     K0  c2[x, y]  cvf[i - 1][x, y] + pi + noise[x, y]/2 == 0};


bc1 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[#[x, y], x == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{1, 0}]] & /@ {cv, mu, c1, c2}; bc2 = 
 PeriodicBoundaryCondition[#[x, y], y == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 1}]] & /@ {cv, mu, c1, c2};

Do[{cvf[i], muf[i], c1f[i], c2f[i]} = 
    Quiet@NDSolveValue[{eq, bc1, bc2}, {cv, mu, c1, 
       c2}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];, {i, 1, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming 

Visualization
Table[DensityPlot[c1f[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", i   dt }], PlotRange -> All], {i, 10, 100,
   10}]


Table[DensityPlot[c2f[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", i   dt }], PlotRange -> All], {i, 10, 100,
   10}]


Table[DensityPlot[cvf[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", i  dt  }], PlotRange -> All], {i, 10, 100,
   10}]


Pictures from the last step can be mapped at large region as follows
cp1 = DensityPlot[c1f[nn][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"c1"}]]
TT1 = Flatten[
   Table[MapAt[Translate[#, {t1, t2}] &, cp1, 1], {t1, -5, 
     5}, {t2, -5, 5}]];

Show[TT1]
cp2 = DensityPlot[c2f[nn][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"c2"}]]

TT2 = Flatten[
   Table[MapAt[Translate[#, {t1, t2}] &, cp2, 1], {t1, -5, 
     5}, {t2, -5, 5}]];

Show[TT2]
cp = DensityPlot[cvf[nn][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"cf"}]]

TT = Flatten[
   Table[MapAt[Translate[#, {t1, t2}] &, cp, 1], {t1, -5, 5}, {t2, -5,
      5}]];

{Show[TT1],Show[TT2],Show[TT]}


Update 1. Hexagonal structure also can be simulated using one cell as follows
<< NDSolve`FEM`
Lx = Sqrt[2]; Ly = 
 Sqrt[2]; scale = 1; nsteps = 400; \[CapitalDelta]t = 5*10^0; dt = 
 1./50; nn = 50;
reg = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 
      0}, {-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}}*scale];

\[Gamma] = 0.5; K0 = 0.16/2; p = 0.016/2; pv = p; pi = p/3; Mv = 0.3;
noiseAmplitude = 10^(-5); co0 = 0.0;

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.002];

n = Length[mesh["Coordinates"]];
noise = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
   noiseAmplitude*(RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n])];
cvf[0][x_, y_] := 0
muf[0][x_, y_] := 0
c1f[0][x_, y_] := 0
c2f[0][x_, y_] := 0
c3f[0][x_, y_] := 0


{mesh["Wireframe"], 
 DensityPlot[noise[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AspectRatio -> Automatic]}


R120 = RotationMatrix[2 Pi/3];
R240 = RotationMatrix[4 Pi/3];
D1 = {{10., 0.}, {0., 0.1}};
D2 = Transpose[R120] . (D1 . R120);
D3 = Transpose[R240] . (D1 . R240);

eq = {-(cv[x, y] - cvf[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Mv Laplacian[mu[x, y], {x, y}] - 
     K0 cvf[i - 1][x, y] (c1[x, y] + c2[x, y] + c3[x, y]) + pv + 
     noise[x, y] == 
    0, (1 - cvf[i - 1][x, y])^2 cv[x, 
       y] + (1 - cv[x, y]) cvf[i - 1][x, y]^2 - 
     mu[x, y] - \[Gamma] Laplacian[cv[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    0, -(c1[x, y] - c1f[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Div[D1 . Grad[c1[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
     K0 c1[x, y] cvf[i - 1][x, y] + pi + noise[x, y]/3 == 
    0, -(c2[x, y] - c2f[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Div[D2 . Grad[c2[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
     K0 c2[x, y] cvf[i - 1][x, y] + pi + noise[x, y]/3 == 
    0, -(c3[x, y] - c3f[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Div[D3 . Grad[c3[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
     K0 c3[x, y] cvf[i - 1][x, y] + pi + noise[x, y]/3 == 0};


bc1 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[#[x, y], x == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{Lx, 0}]] & /@ {cv, mu, c1, c2, c3}; bc2 = 
 PeriodicBoundaryCondition[#[x, y], y == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, Ly}]] & /@ {cv, mu, c1, c2, c3}; eps = 
 10^-8; bc0 = 
 PeriodicBoundaryCondition[#[x, y], 
    Abs[y - (x + scale) Sqrt[3]] <= eps, 
    TranslationTransform[{3/2  scale, -Sqrt[3]/2*scale}]] & /@ {cv, 
   mu, c1, c2, c3}; bc12 = 
 PeriodicBoundaryCondition[#[x, y], Abs[y + Sqrt[3]/2*scale] <= eps, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, Sqrt[3]*scale}]] & /@ {cv, mu, c1, c2, 
   c3}; bc21 = 
 PeriodicBoundaryCondition[#[x, y], 
    Abs[y + (x + scale) Sqrt[3]] <= eps, 
    TranslationTransform[{3/2  scale, Sqrt[3]/2*scale}]] & /@ {cv, mu,
    c1, c2, c3};

Do[{cvf[i], muf[i], c1f[i], c2f[i], c3f[i]} = 
    Quiet@NDSolveValue[{eq, bc0, bc12, bc21}, {cv, mu, c1, c2, 
       c3}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];, {i, 1, nn}] // AbsoluteTiming

Visualization
cp = DensityPlot[cvf[50][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLabel -> Row[{"cvf" }], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

We can expend cp using
TTy = Flatten[
  Table[MapAt[Translate[#, {0, Sqrt[3]*scale  t2}] &, cp, 1], {t2, -4,
     4 }]]; TTxy = 
 Flatten@Table[
   MapAt[Translate[#, R120 . {0, Sqrt[3]*scale  t1}] &, TTy[[i]], 
    1], {t1, -4, 4 }, {i, Length[TTy]}]; TTyx = 
 Flatten@Table[
   MapAt[Translate[#, R240 . {0, Sqrt[3]*scale  t1}] &, TTy[[i]], 
    1], {t1, -4, 4 }, {i, Length[TTy]}];
Show[TTxy]



Thanks, clever solution with Translate
